# c++ How does compiler know that a parameter is an STL container?

Tags: c++, templates, intellisense

c++ newbie question - How can the C++ compiler know that the parameter to a template function has has STL methods as members? in C# you tell a generic method that a parameter has a type constraint, most commonly. it must implement an interface, but with c++ templates there is no restriction on the parameter type.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
void DisplayContents (const T& Input)
{
    for (auto iElement = Input.cbegin() // no intellisense
    ; iElement != Input.cend()
    ; ++ iElement )
    cout << *iElement << ' ';

    cout << endl;
}
int main ()
{
    std::list <int> listIntegers;
    listIntegers.push_front (10);
    listIntegers.push_front (2011);
    listIntegers.push_back (-1);
    listIntegers.push_back (9999);
    DisplayContents(listIntegers);
    //  DisplayContents(99); // neither of these will compile
    //  DisplayContents(new string("")); //
return 0;
}
```

so, in the templated method DisplayContents<>(const T& Input) , there is no intellisense on Input. When you type the period character, no suggestions pop up (which isn't that suprising since the function parameter hasn't specified that the input must be a list or any other type of STL container).

However, if you try and send something that isn't an STL container into DisplayContents<>(const T& Input), then the compiler throws these errors:-

- error C2100: illegal indirection
- error C2228: left of '.cbegin' must have class/struct/union
- error C3536: 'iElement': cannot be used before it is initialized

suggesting that the compiler does know something about the type of the parameter needing to have some basic characteristics.

Can anyone please explain how the compiler "knows" that cbegin() and * operator can be used when a list is sent as the parameter, but not when a string or an int is sent, when apparently the type isn't known as intellisense isn't picking up the method cbegin() ?

Comment: It doesn't know until the code is instantiated. It tries to instantiate the function body with whatever template arguments you give it, and then will give you an error if the functions are not actually valid members of that type. On a related note, you might want to look at [Concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)), an upcoming feature of C++, which allow you to place requirements on template types.

Comment: To add: Intellisense can't do this because it doesn't check which types are being passed to the function. First of all, this is difficult because it would have to look at every single instantiation of the function in your project and find the intersection of their members (and this assumes that all instantiations are giving correct types). Second of all, it is impossible in many situations, such as in a library header, where you simply cannot tell every single type that might be passed. It can be done at compile-time, however, because to compile the code we have to instantiate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite simple, really.  The compiler will pretend that `T` is the type of argument you passed in and then proceed with compilation.  If it runs into any errors then it will report those.  As long as the type of argument you use *would* work if you hard-coded that type then it *will* work.

In your case, it fails with int because an int has no `cbegin()` method.

It fails with `new std::string("")` because the argument type becomes `std::string * const &`, and you can't call `.cbegin()` on this pointer.  (You would have to call `->cbegin()` instead.)

However, you *can* call it with `std::string("")` (note the lack of `new`) which will cause the argument to be `const std::string &`, and this will compile.

So it has nothing at all to do with the compiler "knowing that `T` represents a standard container."  If you create a simple type with `cbegin()` and `cend()` methods and make sure that the return values from those methods can be incremented, dereferenced, and compared for equality, that type would work just as well.

([Here is a demo](http://ideone.com/IBDymw) of your template function working with a user-defined type.)

Comment: And we use SFINAE to make the compiler fail earlier, so we can provide different versions of our algorithms for template-types offering different interfaces.

Comment: Thanks @cdhowie, I'd been wondering why string didn't work. Still, if the compiler is smart enough to pretend the type does support a method, why can't intellisense pick up the methods in the for loop declaration?

Comment: @Dave00Galloway Because at that point the IDE doesn't know what `T` represents; indeed it could represent *any type at all*. Quite simply, any results from intellisense would not even be useful.

Comment: @Dave00Galloway: We can have templates a hundred levels deep, and each might have a dozen variants (specializations) depending on what interface your template-arguments offer. That's a DOS-attack on intellisense...

Comment: @Dave00Galloway I have added an example of a user-defined type working with your template function.

Answer (score 0):

Template used to make generic code.

And here the compiler will generate three overload functions for you.

```
void DisplayContents (const std::list<int>& Input)
void DisplayContents (const int& Input)
void DisplayContents (string* const & Input)
```

obviously version 2 and 3 won't compile, type `const int&` and `string* const&` does not have method cbegin() nor cend()

PS: version 3 param should be `string* const& Input`, thanks to  cdhowie

Comment: As someone pointed out to me, the third signature would actually be `std::string * const &` (reference to constant pointer to string, not reference to pointer to constant string).